# How to make prompt in every time check and returns false if were false and displays the result if were true?

Tags: python, python-2.7

my question is: let's assume that we have prompt on Python and we need to compare prompt and list in case that prompt value doesn't exist in the list will return false in every time we are writing word doesn't exist in a list
but in a case was the value is True, then the script will be running
How can I run this code? 
my language is intermediate sorry if there are some wrongs in grammar

```
list = ["football", "tennis"]

answer = raw_input("What is your favorite sport?")

def fav():
    for i in list:
        if answer in list:
            return answer
        elif answer not in list:
            while True:
                answer2 = raw_input("There is not this sport in your profile please try again")
                return answer2
print fav()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the `for` loop. Also your first `raw_input` should be part of the function.

```
list = ["football", "tennis"]

def fav():
    while True:
        answer = raw_input("What is your favorite sport?")
        if answer in list:
            return answer
        print "There is not this sport in your profile please try again"

print fav()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["football", "tennis"]
answer = raw_input("What is your favorite sport?")

def fav(answer):
    while answer not in list:
        answer = raw_input("There is not this sport in your profile please try again")
    return answer
fav(answer)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanks a lot for this advice my bro. I'll work on :)